# Ora-00257 and occi

Tags: c++, oracle, occi

I have a c++ application which uses occi for connecting with database. I am using occi connection pool mechanism. Recently I have got an error ORA-00257 and it looks like after that nothing is working.
Can you please advice how to handle ora-00257 using occi?

Answer (score 0):

Did you even try to google `ORA-00257`?

First match:
"How to Fix ORA-00257: archiver error. Connect internal only, until freed. A very common Oracle database error that is basically telling you that you have run out of logical or physical space on the mount, disk, or your db_recovery_file_dest location that holds your archivelogs."

Comment: That I have seen but that has to be done at the database side. My question was related to my application. From application, how we should handle such error? Is there any particular guidance to handle such error in occi perspective? It looks like, after this error, occi connection pooling mechanism itself had failed

Comment: If the disk is full, the application can't do anything. Not even deleting data helps, as the logging is not possible.